# Splitting a file using Map Reduce

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, emr

I would like to split the content of a text file into 2 different files using EMR.
The input file, as well as the mapper and reducer scripts are all stored in AWS' S3.
Currently, my mapper reformats the inputs of stdin by tab-delimiting each field throughout the entire file.

```
import sys
import time

first_line = True

for line in sys.stdin:
    if first_line == True:
            first_line = False
            continue
    line= line.strip()
    data=line.split('|')
    d = data[0]
    for i in range(1,len(data)):
            d = d + '\t' +str(data[i])
    d = d+ '\n'
    print d
```

My reducer is where the magic happens.
I would like the reducer to split this text file into 2 different files based on the value of specific fields.
Here's my current reducer.py code

```
mobile_inquiries = open("reducer_output/mob_inq.txt", "a")
transactions = open("reducer_output/transactions.txt", "a")
mob_merchant_id='"99031479997"'
mob_response_code = '"0"'
mob_request_codes = ['"400"','"401"','"402"','"403"','"450"','"408"','"2400"','"2401"','"2402"','"2408"','"6400"','"6405"','"6450"']

for line in sys.stdin:          
    line= line.strip()
    data=line.split('\t')
    d = data[0]
    merchant_id = data[4]
    request_code = data[10]
    response_code = data[19]

# Writes to mobile inquiry file
    if (merchant_id == mob_merchant_id) and (response_code == mob_response_code) and (request_code in mob_request_codes):
        d = d + '\t' +str(data[9])+ '\t' + str(data[28])+'\n'               
        mobile_inquiries.write(d)
# Writes to transaction file
    else:
        d = d + '\t' +str(data[9])+ '\t' + str(data[6])+ '\t' + str(data[4])+ '\t' + str(data[26])+ '\t' + str(data[10])+ '\t' + str(data[19])+ '\t' + str(data[28])+ '\n'
        transactions.write(d)
mobile_inquiries.close()
transactions.close()
```

This EMR job fails and returns the following error message: Shut down as step failed.
I have tested both of these scripts locally using fileReaders on each line and it works. Importing the task to EMR is causing the problem.
My questions are:
 - Is it possible to split a file into 2 or more files using EMR?
 - If so, is S3 preventing me from dynamically creating new files hence failing the EMR job?
 - Or is my code behaving wrongly?

I appreciate any and all feedback.

Thank you.

Comment: Just a quick comment about putting together a CSV row: You can use '\t'.join(list_) more easily.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to do this cannot work. Even if the job succeeded - you would have just managed to write the files to the local file system on each node in the Hadoop cluster. Most likely - these files would be discarded once the job completes.

What's odd is that even though the mapper emits a key\tvalue structure - the reducer doesn't seem to do anything on the collection of values for a given key. so it's not clear why even bother splitting the map output by data[0]? (Perhaps I don't understand the context)

If possible - these would be better alternatives:

- split the input data into two data sets (mobile_inquiries and transactions) first using a map-only job. If you were willing to use Hive - you can select a single table and insert into two directories (in HDFS or S3) based on a predicate (just like the one in the Python code)
- now that the input has been split - run one map-reduce job on each of the outputs. this can do any map/reduce functions. FWIW - the map-reduce functions encoded here don't really need Python - can be expressed straight in standard Hive SQL.

Comment: An update on this.
I figured out with some help that my first step will be a mapper only job. The job will split an input file into mobile inquiries and transactions based on the values of some fields. I am able to separate these records and my resulting output files are correct. However, I want them to be split into 2 files instead of files based off the number of reducers running. I am reading about MultipleTextOutputFormat and trying to find a way to incorporate this using python or into AWS EMR's additional parameters. So far unsuccessfully. Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: why do you care about the number of files?

Comment: Here is the scenario, I have 1 file with records in it. I need to flag records true or false based on certain conditions. I then need to compare the true records with the false records to extract another type of record.
My first goal is to split the original file into 2 files with each type of true and false values in them. Later I will use EMR to perform a join operation based on a key to extract the final type of record I need.

Comment: hadoop (and hive) work mostly at the directory level. it suffices to break your input into two directories. EMR or Hive will then be able to join these two directories.